# Connect Sitecore to External source for data authoring

Tags: sitecore-client, webapi

We have an external data source (SQL or via API). That data needs to be managed by our content authors. i am looking at something this can be done by tool or minimal customization. I tried to create my own page using SPEAK Ui and it doesn't work.

This is what i want to do. I have an api call that can do the CRUD operations. i need to do a way where i can

1. Search for a record [GET call] Load the response data in an item
2. Allow content authors to edit and
3. on save / publish -> push it to the api. [This is something i have done before by creating
   the pipeline on item save. ]

i would need help / ideas on how to do #1 only.

Any Pointers?

Comment: Have you looked on Data Exchange Framework: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/def/60/data-exchange-framework/en/data-exchange-framework.html ?

Comment: You might want to create a custom data provider... this way your data is not transferred into the standard Sitecore databases but you can make them visible and editable in the content editor.

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-are-some-appropriate-uses-for-sitecore-data-providers